# Get form data at node server side on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am trying to submit form data using Ajax call .  Relevant form code goes like .

```
<form target="_blank" id="addCaseForm" class="form-horizontal col-md-12" action="" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Patient Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patientName" name="patientName" placeholder="" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    .. .. .. .. ..
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-xs">Save</button>

</form>
```

On click of submit button the below event is getting called where I am doing normal Ajax call to node.js server to submit form data.   Firstly I have serialized the form data and passed it to request.sent as additional parameters .

But how to get this data in server side . I tried multiple ways to get data  like **req.body. patientName** , **req.params(‘patientName’)** but nothing worked. I am missing something  .

```
$("#addCaseForm").submit(function(event) {
    var postData = $(this).serialize(); 
   // "patientName=rtgh&patientFatherName=5tryh&patientDob=10%2F08%2F2014&patientBloodGroup=o&patientAge=25&patientSex=M&patientNationality=Indian&patientPhone=76&Specilizationtag=3&patientDesc=uyhjn"
    event.preventDefault();
    var request;    
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (tryMS) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (otherMS) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (failed) {
                request = null;
            }
        }

    }

    if (request == null) {
        console.log("Error::Unable to create request object at add new case");
        return false;
    }
    request.open('POST', '/addNewCase', true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                console.log("Form successfully submitted");
            }
        }
    };
    request.send(postData);
});
```

**How to get form data at node server side ?**

I am using express and node code is below

```
exports.addNewCase = function(req,res){
    var Specilizationtag = [],
        attachemntTag = [];
    Specilizationtag = req.params('Specilizationtag').split(',').map(function(eachTag){
        return parseInt(eachTag);
    });


    var patient = new Patient({  

          name: req.params('patientName'),
          fatherName:   req.params('patientFatherName'),
          dob:new Date(req.params('patientDob')),
          bloadGroup : req.params('patientBloodGroup'),
          age:req.params('patientAge'),
          sex: req.params('patientSex'),
          nationality:req.params('patientNationality'),
          phone: req.params('patientPhone'),
          description: req.params('patientDesc'),
          specialization:Specilizationtag,
          attachmentId:attachemntTag});

    patient.save(function(err){
        if(err) {console.log("Error Occured"+err);};

    });
    res.end();
};
```

Comment: You're sending your data with a POST request and trying to retrieve it with GET parameters on your server side.

Comment: How to get data with POST?@BenFortune

Comment: With the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware.

Comment: I am using express framework and it is having body parser ,  but how to extract there additional parameter which is been sent

Comment: If you're already using body-parser then you can get the POST data using `req.body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding content type in request object fixed the problem .

Call setRequestHeader() and set its content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". This is needed for any POST request made via Ajax.

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```